# Changing fonts in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've change default fonts of body tag, for some reason things are not aligned.

[image: Default]

After changing fonts to

```
body{
  font-family: "Myriad Pro Regular", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

I got this

[image]

I've no idea why it is happening. I've tried changing fonts size, padding etc

Here is an image of panel-heading with no padding. Space below "FOLLOWING" is the problem.

[image: Panel-heading with no padding]

Comment: It works right away -> http://jsfiddle.net/cy0kx44o/117/ you must have something else that is altering the CSS layout. Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: I am trying to add Myriad Pro Regular font to jsfiddle

Comment: try adapting the `line-height`..

Comment: You should post the code (a complete, working example) being altered by the font as well. [mcve]

Comment: I've tried line-height. text stays at it position.

Comment: In case you haven't understood:  your question is missing information which would be needed to assist you any further.  Also, you describe alignment issues but I cannot detect any given the images provided above...  both versions of the top 2 images are aligned properly (as far as I can tell) with only a noticeable font change.  Provide us with a more helpful CSS snippet as well as a clearer question regarding your problem!  Then we can help you :)

Comment: Well I am trying to reproduce this problem on jsfiddle using the font that I've used.

Comment: @Waqas is your website live on the server? If yes than share the link and we could help you more on this problem. Or open this page is your browser and go to inspect element and try changing the css properties and you will know whats the problem there